# Using Eclipse Templates for Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, eclipse, actionscript, templates, code-snippets

One of my favorite features in Eclipse is the templates in PDT. In case you don't know what they are, think of writing "function" and having Eclipse write all the syntactical features and let you jump from variable to variable with a tap of the tab key. So I'm starting to do write AS3 in Eclipse and I miss having the templates at my fingertips.

Is there a way I can configure templates in Eclipse for Actionscript development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Eclipse Plugin are you using for Actionscript ?

I'm using FDT which includes templates (Prefereces>FDT>Editor>Templates).

EDIT:

It's not directly included in FLEX Builder. Here's a workaround (not tested) :

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=13507

Comment: Ah, yeah, I should have mentioned that. I'm using Flex Builder plugin.

Comment: Did this work out properly ? I'd be able to remove the "(not tested)" in case others are interested ...